# Change Seaborn heatmap Y-ticklabels font color for alternate labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap

I have a seaborn heatmap with more than 100 labels on Y-axis. I want to change the font color of the Y-labels to red and blue in alternate way.
If I have 10 Y-labels, then 5 labels should have the blue font & 5 labels should have the red font in an alternate fashion.

Kindly Help

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? Any google searches/documentation you have read for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using `ax.ticklabel.font()`. You can even use font to easily differentiate the neighbors. A sample code is given here.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
for i, tick_label in enumerate(ax.axes.get_yticklabels()):
    if i%2:
        tick_label.set_color("blue")
        tick_label.set_fontsize("15")
    else:
        tick_label.set_color("red")
        tick_label.set_fontsize("10")
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While enumerating as @Redox suggested is necessary, you need a flexible solution in case your label is a string, which is common in heatmaps.
Refer to `[matplotlib documentation][1]` for more info.
Credit to @gasvom for inspiring with his answer `[here][1]`.

So I would execute as so:

```
    import numpy as np; 
    import seaborn as sns; 
    uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
    ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
    for i, tick_label in enumerate(ax.axes.get_yticklabels()):
        if tick_label.get_text()=="a string of your choice":
            tick_label.set_color("blue")
            tick_label.set_fontsize("15")
        else:
            tick_label.set_color("red")
            tick_label.set_fontsize("10")
```